# Proper way to connect signals to USB Type-C receptacle

Tags: usb, differential, usb-c

I am trying to follow the design in this schematic [link](https://numato.com/help/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/CallistoK7Sch.pdf) at page 9.

[image]

The schematic above is connecting only RX1 TX1 and D1 data lines on the USB-C receptacle. And there are no pins shown for the other pairs in the USB-C standard (RX2, TX2, D2).

Does this imply leaving the other pairs floating?

I only need my USB-C receptacle to properly transfer my RX, TX and D signals. And couldn't figure out what to do. I spent a lot of time Googling the matter. Using a MUX as TI's HD3SS3220 could be my best chance. But I really want to know if I can just leave these pins floating, voiding extra components.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to refer to the [USB Type-C Specification](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-revision-20-august-2019-and-ecns). (The [USB Implementers Forum](https://www.usb.org/) has these and other documents.)

One of the main features of the Type-C connector is that it can be flipped. I think section 4.5.1.1 of the linked document may be of most interest to you:

> Since the USB Type-C plug can be inserted in either right-side-up or upside-down position, the hosts and devices that support USB data bus functionality must operate on the signal pins that are actually connected end-to-end. In the case of USB 2.0, this is done by shorting together the two D+ signal pins and the two D− signal pins in the host and device
>   receptacles. In the case of USB 3.2 SuperSpeed USB or USB4 TX/RX signals in a single-lane
>   implementation, it requires the functional equivalent of a switch in both the host and device to appropriately route the TX and RX signal pairs to the connected path through the cable. For a USB 3.2 SuperSpeed USB or USB4 dual-lane implementation, the host and/or device resolves the lane ordering.

I'm not quite sure how your project fits into the various examples given, but I think that you'll likely find what you're looking for there.